# Universal Windows App - the equivalent of NW.JS's typeof process == "object"

Tags: win-universal-app, nw.js

In NW.JS we checked to see if we are in a NW.JS app with the following:

```
typeof process == "object"
```

If it is `true` then we are in the NW.JS app rather than an online web page. Because in an online web page this would be `false`.

However, when we are in a javascript Universal Windows App `typeof process == "object"` is also `false`, making the program think we are in an online web page.

So the question is, what check can I do which will return `true` if I am in a Universal Windows App written in javascript, but will return `false` when I am on an online web page or a NW.JS app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the question is, what check can I do which will return true if I am in a Universal Windows App written in javascript, but will return false when I am on an online web page or a NW.JS app?

The `Windows` and `MSApp` object only exists in UWP app, so you can use following codes to check if you are currently running an UWP app:

```
if (typeof Windows!="undefined" && typeof MSApp !="undefined")
{
    //currently you are running a UWP app not a web app or NW.js app
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test `process.versions['nw']` for NW.js app.